# Adding values (Quantity) to a MSSQL database using VBscript

Tags: sql, vbscript

I have Vbscript that modifies an existing record in a table in MSSQL:

```
Command.CommandText = "UPDATE Tabela_san SET Tabela_san.ilosc_na_roli = '" & ilosc_na_roli_form_id & "' WHERE  Tabela_san.ID = '" & ID_variable & "'"
```

The second script to an existing record in the MSSQL database adds only a character in the form of a value but does not increment it or sum it:

```
Command.CommandText = "update Tabela_san set Tabela_san.ilosc_na_roli = Tabela_san.ilosc_na_roli + '" & ilosc_na_roli_form_id & "'  WHERE  Tabela_san.ID = '" & ID_variable & "'"
```

The third script adds a value of 5 to the selected record and increases it by 5:

```
Command.CommandText = "update Tabela_san set Tabela_san.ilosc_na_roli = Tabela_san.ilosc_na_roli + 5  WHERE  Tabela_san.ID = '" & ID_variable & "'"
```

I would like the script to populate a number (quantity) of the `ilosc_na_roli_form_id` and call it with a script button added to the MSSQL database a value from the field `ilosc_na_roli_form_id` to the value contained in the MSSQL database summing it.

To work as a third script, but instead of constant 5, you could use the variable `ilosc_na_roli_form_id` (edit field) to sum the values ​​contained in the database.
So for example:
5 + 2 = 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to pass the value dynamically instead of constant then you can use this

```
Command.CommandText = "update Tabela_san set Tabela_san.ilosc_na_roli = Tabela_san.ilosc_na_roli + " & cInt(ilosc_na_roli_form_id) & " WHERE  Tabela_san.ID = '" & ID_variable & "'"
```